# Increment Count column by 1 base on a another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this data frame where i need to create a count column base on my distance column. I grouped the result by the model column. What i anticipate to get is an increment by 1 on the next count row each time the distance is 100. For example, here is what I have so far but no success yet with the increment

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['A', '34', 3], ['A', '55', 5], ['A', '100', 7], ['A', '0', 1],['A', '55', 5],
     ['B', '90', 3], ['B', '0', 1], ['B', '1', 3], ['B', '21', 1],['B', '0', 1],
     ['C', '9', 7], ['C', '100', 4], ['C', '50', 1], ['C', '100', 6],['C', '22', 4]],
    columns=['Model', 'Distance', 'v1'])

df = df.groupby(['Model']).apply(lambda row: callback(row) if row['Distance'] is not None else callback(row)+1)
print(df)
import numpy as np
(
    df.groupby('Model')
    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(Bount=x.Count  + x.Distance.shift()
                              .eq('100').replace(False, np.nan)
                              .ffill().fillna(0)
                             )
          )
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)

Result with your code solution

Model   Distance    v1  Count
A           34      3   1.0
A           55      5   2.0
A           100     7   3.0
A           0       1   5.0
A           55      5   6.0
B           90      3   1.0
B           0       1   2.0
B           1       3   3.0
B           21      1   4.0
B           0       1   5.0
C           9       7   1.0
C           100     4   2.0
C           50      1   4.0
C           100     6   5.0
C           22      4   6.0


My expected result is:


Model   Distance    v1  Count
A           34      3   1.0
A           55      5   2.0
A           100     7   3.0
A           0       1   5.0
A           55      5   6.0
B           90      3   1.0
B           0       1   2.0
B           1       3   3.0
B           21      1   4.0
B           0       1   5.0
C           9       7   1.0
C           100     4   2.0
C           50      1   4.0
C           100     6   5.0
C           22      4   7.0
```

Take a look at the C group that are two distance equal to 100

Comment: not directly related to your answer but in your code i'd suggest instead of the apply function, you use a cumcount() + 1 to get your count. Then you could apply Allen's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Model': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C', 14: 'C'}, 
                   'Distance': {0: '34', 1: '55', 2: '100', 3: '0', 4: '55', 5: '90', 6: '0', 7: '1', 8: '21', 9: '0', 10: '9', 11: '23', 12: '100', 13: '33', 14: '23'}, 
                   'v1': {0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 7, 3: 1, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 3, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 7, 11: 4, 12: 1, 13: 6, 14: 4}, 
                   'Count': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 4, 9: 5, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 5}})
```

If the logic needs to be applied across the Model column, you can use a shift, compare and add 1 for eligibal rows:

```
df.loc[df.Distance.shift().eq('100'), 'Count'] += 1
```

If the logic needs to be applied at per Model group, then you can use a groupby:

```
(
    df.groupby('Model')
    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(Count=x.Distance.shift().eq('100') + x.Count))
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)
```

Based on @StringZ's updates, below is the updated solution:

```
(
    df.groupby('Model')
    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(Count=x.Count + x.Distance.shift()
                              .eq('100').replace(False, np.nan)
                              .ffill().fillna(0)
                             )
          )
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)

Model   Distance    v1  Count
0   A   34          3   1.0
1   A   55          5   2.0
2   A   100         7   3.0
3   A   0           1   5.0
4   A   55          5   6.0
5   B   90          3   1.0
6   B   0           1   2.0
7   B   1           v3  3.0
8   B   21          1   4.0
9   B   0           1   5.0
10  C   9           7   1.0
11  C   23          4   2.0
12  C   100         1   3.0
13  C   33          6   5.0
14  C   23          4   6.0
```

Comment: What if 100 is on the last row of the group? with this code, the first value of the next group will get bumped by 1

Comment: Don't know if the logic needs to be applied at per group level or entire column

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Allen, I ran your solution, it worked but it was incremented by 2 instead of 1. I got a 6 instead of 5 in my result on the fourth and the tenth rows. Am not sure why even though i see that you only incremented by 1

Comment: @Allen So i increased the data to see the output with your solution, i got a duplicate of 5 in the third and fourth index rows as well as in the 13th and 14th rows. Looks like when i increase the data, it incremented well but i wanted the next row to continue with the count until it gets to the next group before it restarts. See my Expected result above, i updated it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey @Stringz, please see my updates to see if it works.

Comment: @Allen I tried it, it did not work. i got the normal count

Comment: @Stringz, can you copy the setup code in my answer and try the solution again? It worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: @Allen, Am sorry to call you back, I implemented the solution you provided and noticed it did not continue the count if there are two distances that are 100. it skipped after finding the first distance but ignores the skip on the second. I updated the Question using your solution and the result.  See Model C. I believe this might be a minor tweak since you already fix the major part. I will appreciate if you can please take a look one more time